# Using nohup within a loop of a bash script

Tags: bash, shell, loops, unix, nohup

I have a bash script that contains a loop over a list of subdirectories. Inside the loop I `cd` into each subdirectory, run a command using `nohup` and then `cd` back out. In the following example I have replaced the executable by an `echo` command for simplicity.

```
#!/bin/bash
dList=("dname1" "dname2" "dname3")
for d in $dList; do
    cd $d
    nohup echo $d &
    cd ..
done
```

The above causes nohup to hang during the first loop with the following output:

```
$ ./script.sh
./dname1 
$ nohup: appending output to `nohup.out'
```

The script does not continue through the loop and in order to type again on the command line one must press the enter key. 
OK, this is normal `nohup` behaviour when one is using it on the shell, but obviously it doesn't work for my script. How can I get `nohup` to simply run and then gracefully allow the script to continue?

I have already (unsuccessfully) tried variations on the nohup command including

```
nohup echo $d < /dev/null &
```

but that didn't help. 
Further, I tried including

```
trap "" HUP
```

at the top of the script too, but this did not help either. 
Please help!

EDIT: As @anubhava correctly pointed out my loop contained an error which was causing the script to only use the first entry in the array. Here is the corrected version.

```
#!/bin/bash
dList=("dname1" "dname2" "dname3")
for d in ${dList[@]}; do
    cd $d
    nohup echo $d &
    cd ..
done
```

So now the script achieves what I wanted. However, we still get the annoying output from nohup, which was part of my original question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problem is here:

```
for d in $dList; do
```

That will only run `for` loop once for the 1st element of the array.

To iterate over an array use:

```
for d in ${dList[@]}; do
```

---

Full working script:

```
dList=("dname1" "dname2" "dname3")
for d in "${dList[@]}"; do
   cd "$d"
  { nohup echo "$d" & cd -; } 2>/dev/null
done
```